# Mapping Class Diagram into database table design

Tags: sql, uml, class-diagram

I've taken the following class diagram and mapped it into a table design with appropriate keys etc... Am i thinking along the right lines here?

[image: Class Diagram]

[image: Table Design]

Comment: Uhmmm... Where is the diagram?

Comment: http://share.joescott.me/7311edd3.png right there?

Comment: @xBroak (1) the relationship names "hold", "has" are lost after your conversion. I would use naming e.g. "Hold_StaffPositionsID". (2) You can use some ORM schema automatic generator tool (e.g. Toad, Enterprise Architect, GenMyModel) to verify validity of your mapping. If an automatic tool comes to similar conclusion then you're probably right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, but I wonder how should I have found that without you sharing it :) The correctness of your plan mainly depends on your needs. Technically speaking, I believe your diagram is more-or-less correct (not taking into account your needs, as they were not shared in the question). However, I think you should include the identifiers and foreign keys into the diagram as well.

EDIT: For some reason the picture was not showing up and I did not check the console, I believed op forgot to share it, but it turns out that I was wrong.